# In Joomla: custom task resets search filters

Tags: joomla, joomla3.0, helper, jtoolbar

I made custom task (JTOOLBARHELPER:custom) in joomla backend. The last action of task is `$app->redirect( 'index.php?option=com_uzklausos' );` so I guess, because of this all search filters are set to default. How can I do this in other way, so all search filters would stay the same like before my custom task. Btw default joomla tasks (trash, publish) dont have this problem.

Comment: Search filters are there in the request url, as it is a GET request. What _other behaviour_ did you expect when you erase the parameters from the request? Maybe you take a look at how the default is implemented: my bet is that the relevant GET parameters are appended to the request, whenever a redirect is done.

Comment: I already tried that, but it didn't helped. Anyone have any ideas how to do that ?

Answer (score 0):

Try to add appendButton link type instead JToolBarHelper::custom

```
$bar = JToolBar::getInstance('toolbar');
$bar->appendButton('Link', 'ICON', 'TEXT', 'URL');
```